# Authentication with Google Play Games Unity error 403

Tags: unity-game-engine, oauth-2.0, google-play-services, google-play-console

I tried everything to make GPSG to work, lastly I redid everything with this "official" [guide][1]
[1]: https://forum.unity.com/threads/tutorial-authentication-with-google-play-games.1409151/
But I get returned success code canceled and in cloud console it says im trying to auth but it is 403 - forbiden. I am trying to solve it for 5 days i cant solve it adding testing accounts sha1 keystore matching every possible thing only thing i did not do is hit publish and add feature graphics, icon, do i need to do it and if not what is wrong with my setup, i did everything i am supposed to do and everytime 403 canceled......